# Robust linearization

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

In the following [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e0a7/5b33eff3f0116ec5f7321dbe7b51e95347b3.pdf):

> Kuhne, Felipe, Walter Fetter Lages, and JM Gomes da Silva Jr. "Model predictive control of a mobile robot using linearization." In Proceedings of mechatronics and robotics, pp. 525-530. 2004.

They have linearized the system using Jacobian:

$$\boldsymbol{\dot x}_r=\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}_r,\boldsymbol{u}_r)$$

[image: linearization]

Then, I am wondering

1- Is it the only way to linearize the system or are there many methods to linearize and this is only one of them?

2- If there is a disturbance $\boldsymbol{d}$, then using this method, should we calculate the Jacobian around $\boldsymbol{d}_r$ or should we calculate it around zero disturbance? Which one is more common?

3- Is linearization of disturbance in the similar way to the linearization of states and input?

4- Is there any special linearization specific to robust control?